# Why does ls not recognize this declared single-line variable?

Tags: bash, command-line

I'm going through the Linux From Scratch project and I want to verify each of the programs and libs are created properly before I move on from each step.

(I searched here and google but pretty much everything I can find is regarding questions about echoing a var declared in the same line or dumping the output of `ls` to a variable, neither of which apply to my case)

I'll be typing commands similar to the following quite a bit with different patterns:

`ls -ld /tools/lib/mypattern* /tools/bin/mypattern*`

For example:

`ls -ld /tools/lib/tcl* /tools/bin/tcl*`

Since there are repeating uses of the same pattern I'd like to streamline this a bit into something like this:

`glob=mypattern* ls -ld /tools/lib/$glob /tools/bin/$glob`

But if I run:

`glob=tcl* ls -ld /tools/lib/$glob /tools/bin/$glob`

then all I get is this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 lfs lfs 4096 Dec  2 03:02 /tools/bin/
drwxr-xr-x 16 lfs lfs 4096 Dec  2 03:02 /tools/lib/
```

so clearly the variable isn't being picked up properly.

If I run the `ls` with the pattern manually typed in both places then I get the correct output:

```
$ ls -ld /tools/lib/tcl* /tools/bin/tcl*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lfs lfs     8 Dec  2 02:39 /tools/bin/tclsh -> tclsh8.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfs lfs 20512 Dec  2 02:38 /tools/bin/tclsh8.6
drwxr-xr-x 5 lfs lfs  4096 Dec  2 02:38 /tools/lib/tcl8
drwxr-xr-x 6 lfs lfs  4096 Dec  2 02:38 /tools/lib/tcl8.6
-rw-r--r-- 1 lfs lfs  7660 Dec  2 02:38 /tools/lib/tclConfig.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 lfs lfs   773 Dec  2 02:38 /tools/lib/tclooConfig.sh
```

How can I shorten this command so I only have to type the pattern in once each time I run it?

Comment: Aaargh I completely forgot about that expansion. Still learning linux properly, thanks!

Comment: @oguzismail if you make it an answer I'll give you the points

Comment: "echoing a var declared in the same line" ... Pretty much describes what you're doing, just `ls` instead of `echo`, which makes no material difference here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expansions are performed before variable assignments, and command execution comes after. Use [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) instead, like

```
ls -ld /tools/{lib,bin}/tcl*
```